# in iphone 4 which method call when we close application 

Tags: ios4

i want to know which method call when in iphone , application close and  again open.

in iphone4 malty task felicity available . so i want to do background and foreground method for application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

when the user quits an application that supports background execution.

and

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

method is called as part of the transition from the background to the active state. You can use this method to undo many of the changes you made to your application upon entering the background.